Files number of opened tabs in ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 recently. Besides some freezes and bugs, but I have an issue I can't understand. At sidebar, on Files icon, there are a number "2". I think it is number of opened tabs but it is always displayed even when I start or restart the device. Any ideas, please?


I have the same problem. No instance opened but the number one sits there. Sometimes it goes up and down. Very weird.

I too see this number.  It's the number of instances of that program.
If I have firefoxTest open with two profiles I'll see the (2) on the firefoxTest tab.  If I also have open one instance of firefoxProduction (when there is only one instance open you do NOT see a (1) on that tab), that is a different program so I see two of firefoxTest and one of firefoxProduction.  If I now open three instances of my file manager, I'll see (3) on the tab for file manager
. It's as if it is a count of how many of that specific executable are currently running (for that specific process owner or userID).

Well, Thank you but I can't relate to the problem I have. My problem is in "Files" program not Firsfox! IS there something I am missing?

It's not in firefox, it whatever tabs you have open.  That was an example.  I'll edit the answer

Ah now I get it. Any idea how to close it or kill the processes? since even If I am not opening any Files windows, it keeps showing.

Well, thank you for the comment but do you know how to close the opened instance or kill the other processes I mean.

I click on the instances then close them in the traditional manner, clicking on the X at the upper right corner.  If I right click on the tab with the (n), at the bottom is says 'close all' - that closes all instances

That's the problem. No Instance is actually is opened or active. It is just a number without actual active instances
